# ActionBar Sherlock - Display a ProgressBar that turns into a Refresh Button

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have Integrated an ABS into my application. I have an inflated MenuBar that contains a Refresh button. When i click on the refresh button, it should turn into a ProgressBar, and once my refresh call is completed, it should turn back into a Refresh Button. How can i do this ?

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by making the menu have a framelayout or any other layout you want and placing a button and a progress bar on it ...this progress bar should be hidden by default ....

at runtime when u click on the refresh button u can toggle the visibility of the progressbar and button ...when the work of the progress bar is done...again do the same trick....

Answer (score 0):

Put your button inside a FrameLayout and put also inside this framelayout a progressbar with `android:visibility="gone"`, then after loading your data get this progressbar and set the button visibility as visible and the progressbar as gone.

Some pseudo code:

```
private void onDataLoaded(){
   ProgressBar pb = getSupportActionBar.getCustomView().findViewbyId(R.id.pb);
   pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   Button refresh = getSupportActionBar.getCustomView().findViewbyId(R.id.refresh);
   pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```